# Next-Auth Okta Authorization code with PKCE

Tags: oauth-2.0, next.js, okta, pkce, next-auth

I am trying to integrate a NextJS application with Okta, using the Authorization code flow with PKCE. The flow is not complete because the token request is not being performed.

This is the configuration for the provider:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';

const oktaBaseUrl = 'https://my-okta-domain.com/oauth2/[auth-server-id]';
const clientId = '[My Client Id]';

const authorizationUrl =
  oktaBaseUrl +
  '/v1/authorize?response_type=code&response_mode=query&state=false';

const accessTokenUrl = oktaBaseUrl + '/v1/token';
const profileUrl = oktaBaseUrl + '/v1/userinfo';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    {
      id: 'okta',
      name: 'Okta',
      type: 'oauth',
      version: '2.0',
      protection: 'pkce',
      clientId,
      clientSecret: '',
      accessTokenUrl,
      authorizationUrl,
      profileUrl,
      scope: 'services',
      params: {
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      },
      profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.id as string,
          name: profile.name,
          email: profile.email
        };
      }
    }
  ],
});
```

Thefirst stage seems to be perfromed correctly, but when okta returns the code, I only see a message in my application showing an 403 code. It seems it is trying to get the code without perform the request to the token endpoint

[image]

Message in console:

```
[next-auth][error][oauth_get_access_token_error]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_get_access_token_error { statusCode: 403, data: '' } okta y64EzO0u9ZbwqFdjJWqapXggDmC1bWx2DGQaITCpta4
[next-auth][error][oauth_callback_error]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error { statusCode: 403, data: '' }
```

Is there a configuration I am missing?

Comment: You mentioned you are using AuthCode +PKCE flow, but i don't see a code_challenge parameter in your authorise call, you could be doing it wrong.